# Getting disconnected from LAN and Internet after an hour or so - reboot resolves the issue

Tags: networking, lan, internet-connection, wan

Works for an hour maybe two or three and then I lose connection again.

I am running windows 10 on a domain. Latest version W 10 with latest updates. I have scanned for viruses using malware-bytes with nothing to show for it.

I am connected to the computer with SSH and I never lose that connection. When I search google for this problem nothing comes close to matching this experience. Until the disconnect happens all other functions on the workstation seem to be doing just fine. Even after the disconnect the local programs are OK.

Also after it happens I can ping amazon and google from the command window. That means the local DNS service on the Domain server is OK. No other users have complained about this issue. There is one other user connecting over SSH and doing the same activities - Visual Studio development. Their remote computer is on the same switch as mine.

Another symptom. I have a client server application running on my system. That is both the server and client are on this computer. When this problem occurs I can't even connect from the client to the server using the loop back ip address 127.0.0.1.

I will try to do a repair as suggested by John

Comment: Make sure for all Network Cards, in Device Manager - Allow this device to turn OFF is disabled. In Advanced Power Management, make sure Network Cards are set for Maximum Performance (not Power Saving).

Comment: @John Please post as an answer, given that mooncaptain verified it as a working solution

Comment: @John I spoke too soon. The links and network connections remained active for about 24 to 36 hours after I turned off power management for the NIC. A record compared to the 1 to 2 hours I had been seeing. Then it happened again and the only recourse was to reboot. I did double check the power Management tab. Control Panel, Network Connections, (right mouse click on NIC and select Properties, Configure, Power Management, deselect allow computer to turn off... this was still deselected.

This is a wired connection no wireless.

Comment: I added to my answer to do a Windows 10 Repair Install to correct all network components.

Comment: @John - I have not done a repair but I have more information.

Comment: @John - I have not done a repair but I have more information. Another user who is also using RDP over SSH to connect to a workstation at our company site is having the same problem.  That is, can't connect to LAN resources or get to the internet except after a reboot. Also several days passed between the last time I rebooted and the next time it was required. Our company has been using this SSH remote desktop tech for several years now so we have had good results till now.

Comment: Perhaps update or reinstall the SSH client.

Comment: @John - don't know where to put this:  I installed an update to our router on the thought that the default gateway for both my nic and the other user's nic depended on the gateway functioning properly. I installed on the 20th of June - 5 days ago and haven't had a disconnect since. The other user was still having problems. I suggested to them to turn off power management for the nic. Let's say that for now it is looking good and that John's suggestion solved part of the problem. I will report back with results on the other user's luck in a few days.

Comment: @John After doing a Settings / Update & Security / Recovery / Reset the disconnect problem has not reoccurred. So I will mark this as the solution. And add that the reset of the power management option for the NIC also helped extent the time between network access loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devices getting disconnected after an hour is often a power management issue of the devices.

Make sure for all Network Cards, in Device Manager - Allow this device to turn OFF is disabled. In Advanced Power Management, make sure Network Cards are set for Maximum Performance (not Power Saving).

This should fix your issue.

If not, and the issue occurs again do a Windows 10 Repair Install as that will fix most problems. Use the option to Keep Everything.

> Also "SSH remote desktop tech for several years now so we have had
> good results until now"

Perhaps update or reinstall the SSH client. This is additional news to the first post.